# Сыпет или сыплет?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Есть ли вариант "сыпет" или только и исключительно "сыплет"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Лопатина даются такие варианты: *сыпать, сып**л**ю, сып**л**ет, сыплют и сы**пе**т, сы**пя**т*, пов. *сыпь*.

Comment: И что, по Лопатину получается еще один то ли разноспрягаемый глагол, то ли исключение? СыплЮт и сыпЯт? Да... чувствую я , что изучив Лопатина, скоро начну  ошибаться в ЕГЭшных тестах))) Хотя. надо признаться, что тест тестом, а говорю я "сыпят"

Comment: Он не разноспрягаемый. Он альтернативный. У него две полные парадигмы. С "Л" и без него. Примерно как "махаю" и "машу".
Вариант "Сыплет", "Сыплем" и т.д. - старая норма, "Сыпят" признали нормативным сраввнительно недавно.

А пардон, понял. Да, вариант "сыпет" - "сыпят" получается разноспрягаемый.

Comment: Второй вариант (без "л") невозможен в первом лице. Или в скором времени мы будем говорить "сыпю"?

Answer (score 2):

Литературной норме соответствует только вариант с чередованиями в-вл, п-пл, б-бл, м-мл и т.п. : ловить-ловлю, сыпать - сыплю, любить - люблю, разломить-разломлю, дремать - дремлю. Правда, в форме 3 лица ед. и мн. числа таких форм меньше: сыпать - сыплет, сыплют, дремать - дремлет, дремлют и т.д.